# Check if data exists in database and insert new if not found using multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

My requirement is something like this:
I have written a code which checks for data in database and if data is not found, it consumes third party rest API in order to get data. Some logic is performed and finally obtained data is stored in database.

```
 public void exampleMethod(){

      MyObject myObj = getObjFromDatabase(); //getting from db

      if(myObj==null){                       //not found in db
        myObj = getObjFromThirdParty();      //consuming rest api
        //some logic here in case myobj is not in db.... 
      }else{
       //some other logic here in case myobj is in db...
      } 
     saveObjInDatabase(myObj);            //saving it in database
 }
```

I need it to be saved in database just once. Getting response from third party API takes some time and this method gets executed from multiple threads.
Now, the problem is I need it to be saved in database just once, but before one thread could save data in database another thread gets null from database, logic that should get executed only when "data is not in db" gets executed and saves same data more than once. (I am using mongoDB to store data) 
How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: The short answer is "locking". I would say you should probably do locking on the database side so that it will work if you ever have multiple JVMs running this code concurrently against the same database. Will this be the case? If not then you can just use locking within your Java code.

Comment: The context isn't clear but it sounds like multiple threads are creating a `myObj`, where each thread's `myObj` is just a different instance of the _same_ object.  The simplest would be to synchronize `exampleMethod()`.

Comment: synchronizing `exampleMethod()` is probably the simplest solution, but if there are many concurrent reads, that would block a lot with no need to do so. The threads only need to stop and wait if another thread is updating the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking about is caching. Here is an example that should work decently. It synchronizes on `getObj` in case the object needs to be loaded. If the object is fresh then `getObj` returns very quickly and hardly blocks the other threads, but if it needs to load the object then the other threads will wait until the object is loaded.

```
public class Test {

    // used when you want to refresh the cached object
    private static boolean refreshNext = false;

    // a static reference to your object that all threads can use
    private static MyObj cachedObj = null;

    private static void message(String msg) {
        System.out.println(
                System.currentTimeMillis() + " : " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + msg);
    }

    private static void sleep(long milli) {
        try { Thread.sleep(milli); } catch (Exception e) { }
    }

    // represents the object stored in the db
    private static MyObj myObjInDb = null;

    private static void saveObjInDb(MyObj obj) {
        // TODO do real saving to db and handle errors
        message("storing in db...");
        myObjInDb = obj;
    }

    private static MyObj loadObjFromDb() {
        // TODO do real loading from db and handle errors
        message("getting from db...");
        sleep(1000);
        return myObjInDb;
    }

    private static MyObj loadObjFromVendor() {
        // TODO do real fetching from vendor and handle errors
        message("getting from vendor...");
        sleep(2000);
        return new MyObj();
    }

    private static MyObj loadObj() {
        message("loading object...");
        MyObj obj = loadObjFromDb();
        if (obj == null) {
            message("db didn't have it.");
            obj = loadObjFromVendor();
            saveObjInDb(obj);
        }
        return obj;
    }

    /** Returns the object, first loading and caching if needed. */
    public static synchronized MyObj getObj() {
        // only one thread can get the object at a time, in case it needs to be loaded. 
        if (cachedObj == null || refreshNext) {
            // load and cache the object
            cachedObj = loadObj();
            refreshNext = false;
        }
        return cachedObj;
    }

    public static void exampleMethod() {
        MyObj obj = getObj();
        message(obj.toString());
        // ... do stuff with obj
    }

    private static class MyObj {
        public final String data = "I have data!";
        @Override public String toString() { return data; }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            new Thread(Test::exampleMethod).start();
    }
}
```